# Cómo evitar que se repitan los mismo valores

Tags: c#

Estoy creando un programa sobre una nómina. Estoy usando arreglos, y al momento de ingresar valores va bien, pero cuando intento ingresar en el renglón 3, me vuelve a repetir los mismo datos para `horasT` y `horasEx` y no se cómo arreglarlo.

Ya lo intenté todo, pero no consigo hallar una solución.

Este es mi programa:

```
int q = 0;
int t=0;
int ex = 0;
int s = 0;
int valor = Convert.ToInt32(Interaction.InputBox("¿Cuantos vas a ingresar?", " ",null));
trabajador[] trabajador = new trabajador[valor];
textBox1.Text = "Nombre Apellidos Departamento Horas E Horas T Total";
textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
for (int i = 0; i < trabajador.Length; i++)
{
    trabajador[i].nombre = Interaction.InputBox("Nombre:", " ");
    trabajador[i].apellidos = Interaction.InputBox("Apellidos:", " ");
    trabajador[i].dpet = Interaction.InputBox("Escoge uno de los 3 departamentos: C1, C2, C3:", " ");
    trabajador[i].horasT = Convert.ToInt32(Interaction.InputBox("Horas Trabajadas:", " "));
    trabajador[i].horasEx = Convert.ToInt32(Interaction.InputBox("Horas Extras:", " "));
    switch (trabajador[i].dpet)
    {
        case "C1":
            t = trabajador[i].horasEx * 75;
            if (trabajador[i].horasEx >= 25 && trabajador[i].horasT > 0)
            {
                ex = 75 * 2;
                q = trabajador[i].horasT * ex;
            }
            s = t + q;
            break;
        case "C2":
            t = trabajador[i].horasEx * 120;

            if (trabajador[i].horasEx >= 25 && trabajador[i].horasT > 0)
            {
                ex = 120 * 2;
                q = trabajador[i].horasT * ex;
            }
            s = t + q;
            break;
        case "C3":

            t = trabajador[i].horasEx * 80;
            if (trabajador[i].horasEx >= 25 && trabajador[i].horasT > 0)
            {
                q = trabajador[i].horasT * 160;
            }
            s = t + q;
            break;
     }
     textBox1.Text += trabajador[i].nombre + "\t" + trabajador[i].apellidos + "\t" + trabajador[i].dpet + "\t" + trabajador[i].horasT + "\t" + trabajador[i].horasEx + "\t" + t +  "\t" +q + "\t" + s ;
     textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;      
}
```

[image]

Comment: A simple vista, con el código que has subido, no veo el error. Te recomiendo que ejecutes paso a paso tu programa, en depuración, y te darás cuenta rápido de dónde está el error.

Comment: no responde a tu pregunta, pero si s =t +q siempre, no sería mejor sacarlo del case y ponerlo al final?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al recorrer los elementos del `for` se sustituyen los valores de `s` y de `t`, pero no siempre se cumplen las condiciones para que tambien se sustituya `q` por lo que debes asignarle un valor por cada elemento, en este caso, cuando inicies el for debes darle un valor de 0.

```
for (int i = 0; i < trabajador.Length; i++) {
    q = 0;
    //Resto del for
}
```